# Access to a local server from anywhere using a vm on gcloud as mediator

Tags: ssh, gcloud

I made some search around reverse proxy but it does not seem to answer to my problem.

I want to connect from anywhere to a local server without changing anything to the local firewall.

My idea is to establish an ssh connection between the local server to a vm instance on gcloud and then, from anywhere, I connect to this vm instance and reuse this ssh connection.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use serveo.net [link](http://serveo.net)

```
ssh -o serverAliveInterval=60 -R CUSTOMDOMAIN:80:localhost:YOURPORT serveo.net
```

you can access your localhost from any where,it's free of cost

by using url **CUSTOMDOMAIN.serveo.net** you can access your localhost server from any where in the world.(Here CUSTOMDOMAIN means you can use your custom sub domain)

Alternative for serveo is ngrok [link](https://ngrok.com/)